# sir am new to wordpress and i didn't get menu button in appearance field what is the issue can you please explain me

Tags: wordpress

sir am new to wordpress and i didn't get menu button in appearance field what is the issue can you please explain me..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gRPq.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
i got answer for this problem.i used this function for setting menus

function awesome_theme_setup()
{
    add_theme_support('menus');
    register_nav_menu('primary', 'primary Header Navigation');
    register_nav_menu('secondary','Footer Navigation');
}
for only getting menu on sidemenu on the dashboard i used function like
add_theme_support('menus');
```